# Access String Resource from different Class Library

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I would like to know how to load string resource from another class library. Here is my structure.

```
Solution\
    CommonLibrary\
        EmbeddedResource.resx
    MainGUI\
```

If I get the string on classes of CommonLibrary I just use EmbeddedResource.INFO_START_MSG but  when I try to use typed string resource It cannot recognize the resource file. Note that the CommonLibrary is already referenced in the MainGUI.

I usually do it this way.

```
Solution\
    CommonLibrary\
    MainGUI\
        EmbeddedResource.resx
```

But I want to use the same resource on both projects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the reference to the library to the main application.  Make certain that (on the Resources file) the "Access Modifier" is set to public.

Reference the string like so:

```
textBox1.Text = ClassLibrary1.Resource1.ClassLibrary1TestString;
```

I added the resource file via right clicking, thus the "1" in the name.  If you go to the Properties page for the class library and click on the "Resources" tab, you can add the default resources file, which will not have the numeral "1" in the name.

Just make certain your values are public, and that you have the reference in the main project and you should have no issues.

Comment: To be more specific, I changed the "Custom Tool" property of the resx file from "ResXFileCodeGenerator" to "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator".

Answer (score 4):

By default the resource class is `internal` which means it won't be directly available in other assemblies. Try by changing it to `public`. A part from this you will also have to make the string properties in resource class `public`

Answer (score 2):

The is the way I've done it in the past. However, this might not work across assemblies:

```
public static Stream GetStream(string resourceName, Assembly containingAssembly)
{
    string fullResourceName = containingAssembly.GetName().Name + "." + resourceName;
    Stream result = containingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fullResourceName);
    if (result == null)
    {
        // throw not found exception
    }

    return result;
}


public static string GetString(string resourceName, Assembly containingAssembly)
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    Stream sourceStream = GetStream(resourceName, containingAssembly);

    if (sourceStream != null)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(sourceStream))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    if (resourceName != null)
    {
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: This may work but I this using strongly typed variable for string would avoid future mistake in case string resource name are misspelled or changed. up one vote for effort. Also I Fixed the indention of your code.